# How to do sequential while loop in Vert.x

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I have an use case like getting folder path for an item, database schema like this (stored in MongoDB)

```
Item table: {itemID: 100, itemName: 'Vert.X', parentID: 2}

Category table: 
{categoryId:2, categoryName:'Information System', parentID:1}
{categoryId:1, categoryName:'Books', parentID:0}
```

where parentID = 0 is top level category (no record in category table). So we should have a function like this

```
getItemPathByItemId(100) = 'ROOT > Books > Information System';
```

With normal way, I can make a while loop:

```
Category getCategoryByID(int categoryID);

int categoryId = 2; // get parent_id of item
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
while (true) {
   Category c = getCategoryByID(categoryId);
   if (c != null) {
      s.append(c.getName());
      categoryId = c.getParentId();
   }
   else {
      break; 
   }
}
```

I have no idea to achieve this in Vert.X while using VertX MongoClient to query, I have a method to get category name like this

```
public Future<String> getCategoryName(int categoryId) {
    Future<String> future = Future.future();

    mongoClient.findOne("category", new JsonObject().put("categoryId", categoryId), null, res -> {
        JsonObject obj = res.result();
        if (obj != null) {
            future.complete(obj.getString("name"));
        }
        else {
            future.complete("ROOT");
        }
    });

    return future;      
}
```

I know that we can use future.compose() for sequential processing, but not sure how to achieve this in a while loop like this. Thank you all for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. What you're missing is a recursive call to your function again.
 Something like:

```
public Future<String> getCategoryName(int categoryId) {
    Future<String> f = Future.future();
    mongoClient.findOne(categoryId, (res) -> {
        if (res != null) {
            f.complete(getCategoryName(res.parentId).result() + " > " + res.name);
        }
        else {
            f.complete("ROOT");
        }
    });
    return f;
}
```

I must say that those possible-infinite loops are not the best use case for futures, but here you go.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> Future<T> nonBlockingWhile(Supplier<Future<T>> supplier, Predicate<T> predicate, Integer retry) {
    return supplier.get().compose(result -> {
        if (retry <= 0 || predicate.test(result)) {
            return Future.succeededFuture(result);
        }
        return nonBlockingWhile(supplier, predicate, retry - 1);
    });
}
```

Written this generic function, behaving as a non-blocking while loop.

Supplier is analogous to curly braces code block.
Predicate is analogous to condition, inside while clause.

Answer (score 0):

[CompositeFuture](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/CompositeFuture.html) gives you ways to compose many futures, and make something when all have completed, failed, etc.

In your case `all(...)` looks like a good bet.

You may also look into the RxJava2 bindings for the `vertx-mongo` module, see https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/rxjava-2-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/reactivex/database/mongo/Client.java as an example.